# In $\mathbb{Z}[X^2,X^3]$ the $lcm(X^2,X^3)$ and $gcd(X^2 \cdot X^3, X^2 \cdot X^2)$ do not exist

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

In lecture I encountered the following remark:

> In $\mathbb{Z}[X^2,X^3]$ the $lcm(X^2,X^3)$  and $gcd(X^2 \cdot X^3, X^3 \cdot X^3)$ do not exist.

I do not understand this at all, for as far as I can see we can "normally" multiply the $X$'s with each other, so intuitively I would say that $X^3 = lcm(X^2,X^3)$ and $X^4 = gcd(X^2 \cdot X^3, X^2 \cdot X^2)$; since $X^2 \cdot X^3 = X^5$.

Could you please explain that to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GCD is the divisor which all other common divisors divide. $X^3$ and $X^4$ are both common divisors, but neither divides the other in this ring because $X$ is not a part of it.

Similarly, the LCM is the common multiple which divides all other common multiples. $X^5$ and $X^6$ are common multiples of $X^2$ and $X^3$, but neither divides the other.